# Simple dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a simple dropdown menu but the sub items of `Meme` don't stay in block.

[image: Screenshot of menu]

If I remove float left of `header li`, the menu of `Memes` appears under `Home`.

HTML:

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="brand">
            <h1><span class="highlight">My</span> website</h1>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="current"><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="cv.html">Curriculum Vitae</a></li>
                <li><a href="pc.html">PC Gaming</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Memes</a>  
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Hot</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Trending</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Upload File</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>        
</header>
```

CSS:

```css
header {
    background: #35424a;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 30px;
    min-height: 70px;
    border-bottom: #e8491d 3px solid;   
}

header a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
}

header li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;  
}

header #brand {
    float: left;
}

header #brand h1 {
    margin: 0;
}
header nav {
    float:right;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
header .highlight, header .current a {
    color: #e8491d;
    font-weight: bold;
}
header a:hover{
    color: #ccc;
    font-weight: bold;
}
nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
} 
nav ul ul {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
}
nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
    background: #e8491d;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify how you want the sub menu to appear, as your code shows the meme menu in a row?

Comment: vertical. like in a column

Comment: All of your _"doesn't work"_ comments indicate that you have left out something important from your question, as others have mentioned. Also, this could be made into a _snippet_ so it can be seen live here in the question. Finally, it's unclear what you mean when you comment _"doesnt appear"_ — _"doesnt show all"_ and _"doesnt work"_ for which you link to _pictures_, instead of a fiddle, codepen, or plunker. Pictures aren't helpful since we don't know what code produced that picture. See [mcve] in the [SO Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `float:left` off of `header li` and make it `display:inline-block;` instead.

**Edit:** I don't know how it doesn't work then, because it does in this fiddle, with the same code that you provided. There must be other code that you have that is conflicting, that you didn't include.

```css
 header {
    background: #35424a;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 30px;
    min-height: 70px;
    border-bottom: #e8491d 3px solid;   
}

header a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
}

header li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;  
}

header #brand {
    float: left;
}

header #brand h1 {
    margin: 0;
}
header nav {
    float:right;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
header .highlight, header .current a {
    color: #e8491d;
    font-weight: bold;
}
header a:hover{
    color: #ccc;
    font-weight: bold;
}
nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
} 
nav ul ul {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
}
nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
    background: #e8491d;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="brand">
                <h1><span class="highlight">My</span> website</h1>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li class="current"><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="cv.html">Curriculum Vitae</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pc.html">PC Gaming</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Memes</a>  
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Hot</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Trending</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Upload File</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>        
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the float left and change the following:

```
header li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;  
}

nav ul ul {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nhwgh0t3/)

Comment: Did you look at the fiddle?  It is working there, which means there is something else going on that is not part of the code you posted in your question.  Do you have overflow: hidden on a container element?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a flexbox for the embedded menus, it handles with width of the sub-items better than floating does.

You can also change this flex to use `flex-direction: row` if you prefer that to the column.

Had to change a few other things in order to position the absolute element properly based on its parent menu element. But not too much has changed and I even included a following element to show how they will be aligned even with following submenus.

```css
header {
  background: #35424a;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 30px;
  min-height: 70px;
  border-bottom: #e8491d 3px solid;   
}

header a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
}

header li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 20px;  
}

header #brand {
  float: left;
}

header #brand h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
header nav {
  float:right;
}
header .highlight, header .current a {
  color: #e8491d;
  font-weight: bold;
}
header a:hover{
  color: #ccc;
  font-weight: bold;
}
nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: start;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #e8491d;
} 
nav > ul{
  height: 20px;
}
nav ul li{
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
nav ul ul {
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul ul li {
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="brand">
            <h1><span class="highlight">My</span> website</h1>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="current"><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="cv.html">Curriculum Vitae</a></li>
                <li><a href="pc.html">PC Gaming</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Memes</a>  
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Hot</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Trending</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Upload File</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Memes2</a>  
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Hot</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Trending</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Upload File</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>        
</header>
```

Comment: revised a bit for a few padding/centering issues

Comment: look good thx. But my problem is that it doesnt show all. It seems like it doesnt have space on the section https://gyazo.com/330aa60a8ebec82c075939c5a7113e6a

Comment: The problem there is you have an `overflow: hidden` somewhere that you didn't include in the example. That or it's a z-index problem. Try adding a `z-index: 10` or something to the submenu